# Generic diagram generator from markup language

Tags: diagram, wireframing, design

I'm looking for diagram generator (using some markup language as the input) capable of generating generic block-and-arrow diagrams. I would have labeled blocks containing other labeled blocks, and sometimes-labeled lines/arrows between the blocks. I want to list the blocks and let the generator automatically size and place them on a canvas.

I've looked at common diagram generators but they all seem focused on other types of diagrams. Has anyone used something capable of generating this type of diagram?

Comment: PlantUML or Mermaid, perhaps?

Comment: @0xC0000022L I did check out both of these but they can't create this type of diagram, unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You may want to name some you've tried and that didn't work.

Comment: Maybe good to include an image in the question to show what you would like to achieve.  Possibilities that come to my mind are also Graphviz dot  and even LaTeX (specifically  Tikz and friends. Not easy but a lot of possibilities and flexibility. Note I never used Tikz myself though).